# CLLocationManager in background thread

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am doing one application.In that i am using the CLLocationManager Class for getting the updated location latitude and longitude details.But i need to use this CLLocationManager in sepaate thread .I written my code like below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetch) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
-(void)fetch
 {
    manager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    manager.delegate=self;
    manager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

 }
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {
   NSLog(@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
   lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
 }
```

.But this delegate method is not fired when i run this code.So please guide me how to get the location updates in separate thread.

Comment: Are you adding the delegates in your .h file like this @interface Your_ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

Answer (score 2):

The methods of your delegate object are called from the thread in which you started the corresponding location services. That thread must itself have an active run loop, like the one found in your application’s main thread. ——from apple document

Answer (score -1):

Could you please tried with this.

```
 dispatch_async(newThread, ^(void) {

       [self fetch];
   });
```

hope you'll get solved problem.

Comment: App is crashed in this line   dispatch_async(newThread, ^(void) {[self fetch];});

Comment: And i set the location for UIBackgroundModes in Info.Plist.Because i have to tun this app in app suspended mode also.

Answer (score -2):

in .h file

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

//Set Delegate  
    CLLocationManagerDelegate
// Declare
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
    locationupadate=YES;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0f;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

     if(locationupadate)
     {
           NSLog(@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
          lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427140/call-a-function-using-thread-in-xcode

Comment: But delegate method is not firing.

Answer (score -2):

in .h file

```
MainView *ctl;
NSMutableDictionary *dictSubPoses;

- (id)initWithCtl:(MainView*)_ctl;
```

in .m file

```
- (id)initWithCtl:(MainView*)_ctl
{
   if(self = [super init]) 
   {
      ctl = _ctl; //[_ctl retain];
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)main 
{
   [ctl performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:dictSubPoses];
}
```